# Как упорядочить id по порядку

Tags: sql-server

Как сделать что бы id проставлялся по порядку ? У меня после 13 идет 25 и 28.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: order by column_name

Comment: Там просто ранее были строки, потом их удалили вот и получился пробел. А сейчас только пересоздавать таблицу.

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by [id_uchenika]) as [Number]

Comment: А зачем это нужно? Пусть будут пробелы. Чему это мешает? Потом в процессе работы пробелы неизбежно появятся. Каждый раз перенумеровывать?